# Opencv-python VP9 encoding speeds up video

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

When trying to encode a video using opencv writer with vp9 and webm, it happens to be speeded up : it is 4 times faster than in real life. However the frame rate does not change.
e.g. 10 seconds recording at 20fps results in a 2,5 seconds clip at 20fps. The video start a normal frame rate for about 1 sec and then speeds up.
Steps to reproduce :

```
import cv2
import os
import time

CAPTURE_LENGTH = 10 #seconds

#Capture video from webcam
vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'vp09')
output = cv2.VideoWriter("cam_video.webm", fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
start = time.time()

while(time.time() < start + CAPTURE_LENGTH):
     ret,frame = vid_capture.read()
     output.write(frame)
vid_capture.release()
output.release()
```

tested on Ubuntu 18.04 x86 and windows 10 20H2 x86
opencv-python version 4.5.2.52

Comment: what makes you think that VideoCapture gives frames at 20 fps? what makes you think this has anything to do with a specific codec? please add those details to the question, and revise your question if you think it's sensible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are limited by your performance on `vid_capture.read()` and `output.write(frame)`. So you might be able to get your frames in time by implementing asyncio. This way you will start capturing the next frame without waiting to write the previous one and you have a sleep function that spaces out your frame captures to match your frame rate.

```
import cv2
import time
import asyncio

async def captureFrame(vid_capture):
     ret, frame = vid_capture.read()
     return(frame)

async def main():
     CAPTURE_LENGTH = 10  # seconds
     vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
     fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'vp09')
     output = cv2.VideoWriter("cam_video.webm", fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))
     start = time.time()
     frameGets = []
     while (time.time() < start + CAPTURE_LENGTH):
          await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
          frameGets.append(asyncio.create_task(captureFrame(vid_capture)))
     for get in frameGets:
          output.write(await get)
     vid_capture.release()
     output.release()

asyncio.run(main())
```

This puked out the following warning for me but the video did get output so I say it worked.

```
 RN:0@54.875] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (539) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
    OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x39307076/'vp09' is not supported with codec id 167 and format 'webm / WebM'
```

As a side note you don't really need asyncio you just need to get the `output.write` out of the way from the `vid_capture.read` so you can just do:

```
import cv2
import time

CAPTURE_LENGTH = 10 #seconds

#Capture video from webcam
vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'vp09')
output = cv2.VideoWriter("cam_video.webm", fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
start = time.time()
frames = []
while(time.time() < start + CAPTURE_LENGTH):
     ret,frame = vid_capture.read()
     frames.append(frame)
     time.sleep(0.05)
vid_capture.release()
for frame in frames:
     output.write(frame)
output.release()
```

And get fairly reasonable results. Neither of these solutions are perfect tho becasue the time between each frame will be 0.05 seconds + the amount of time to run `frameGets.append(asyncio.create_task(captureFrame(vid_capture)))` or `vid_capture.read()` respectively. if you want your video to be more perfectly timed I guess you want todo something like this:

```
import cv2
import time

CAPTURE_LENGTH = 10 #seconds

#Capture video from webcam
vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'vp09')
output = cv2.VideoWriter("cam_video.webm", fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
start = time.time()
frames = []
frameduration = 0.05
while(time.time() < start + CAPTURE_LENGTH):
     frametop = time.time()
     ret,frame = vid_capture.read()
     frames.append(frame)
     while time.time()-frametop < frameduration:
          pass
vid_capture.release()
for frame in frames:
     output.write(frame)
output.release()
```

However this still won't be perfect but it will likely be close enough. A few points of note here is that you initial problem demonstrates that your hard drive (like most) cannot write fast enough to sustain 20fps. The trouble is that with that in mind now we have to write the frames to RAM in the form of a python array, this will limit your recording duration to a function of your system memory, a limitation we must simply accept. Continuous recording is difficult and the frame rate must be limited to the write speed of the drive for long durations, this is why most security systems have either low frame rates or motion activated recording.